# jquery validation for email allowing blank somehow

Tags: jquery, ajax, validation

I have a contact form. When submitted it uses AJAX to load "/forms/contact_received.php" sends me an email & adds the user's contact info to a db. Something like 10% of the entries in the DB (and their associated emails) don't have email addresses.

I can't seem to replicate the problem. For a while I had the form send me the user-agent in hopes that they all had the same browser but it's a cross section, some safari, some mozilla, some IE, some mobile, some desktop. Furthermore the blank email submissions don't seem malicious either, these are legit questions from actual human beings.

My script looks something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function checkForm() {
  hideAllErrors();
  var formIsValid =
    showErrorAndFocusIf('FieldData0', isEmpty, 'nameError')
    && showErrorAndFocusIf('FieldData2', isEmpty, 'emailError')
    && showErrorAndFocusIf('FieldData2', isAnInvalidEmail, 'emailError2')
    && showErrorAndFocusIf('FieldData1', isEmpty, 'questionError');
  return formIsValid;
}
function showErrorAndFocusIf(fieldId, predicate, errorId) {
  var field = document.getElementById(fieldId);
  if (predicate(field)) {
    document.getElementById(errorId).style.display = 'inline';
    if (field.select) {
      field.select();
    }
    field.focus();
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
function isEmpty(field) {
  return field.value == '';
}
function isAnInvalidEmail(field) {
  var email = field.value;
  var ok = "1234567890qwertyuiop[]asdfghjklzxcvbnm.@-_QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM";
  for(i = 0; i < email.length; i++){
    if(ok.indexOf(email.charAt(i)) < 0) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  re = /(@.*@)|(\.\.)|(^\.)|(^@)|(@$)|(\.$)|(@\.)/;
  re_two = /^.+\@(\[?)[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$/;
  return re.test(email) || !re_two.test(email);
}
function hideAllErrors() {
  document.getElementById("nameError").style.display = "none"
  document.getElementById("emailError").style.display = "none"
  document.getElementById("emailError2").style.display = "none"
  document.getElementById("questionError").style.display = "none"
}
</script>
```

and My HTML looks like this:

```
<style>
.error{display:inline;margin:0;}
</style>

<form id="contact" name="contact" action="">
    <b>Name</b>
    <input class="valid" name="name" value="" maxlength="100" size="30" style="display:block;" type="text">

    <b>Email</b> (will not be published)
    <input class="error" name="email" value="" maxlength="100" size="30" style="display:block;" type="email">
    <label class="error" generated="true" for="email">Please enter a valid email address</label>

    <b>Question</b>
    <textarea class="error" name="message" cols="50" rows="5" style="display:block;"></textarea>
    <label class="error" generated="true" for="message">Please enter your message in the box above</label>
    <input name="page" value="[URL]" type="hidden">
    <input class="btn" value="Contact Us" name="Submit" type="submit">
</form>
```

What could be some possible situations that my validation could be failing? Like I said, the validation works for me just fine and I can't figure out how it would be bypassed.

Comment: javascript disabled in browser?! Anyway, validation should be done server side too

Comment: We're assuming a lot - that the validation methods are ever called (not shown), and if so, when; that your email field either has an id matching `FieldData2` added, or that this is dummy HTML that's still *really* close to the live HTML; that the results of the validation handler aren't ignored; etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your checks are done client-side only, then it's trivial to bypass them.

Any user that has js disabled, for example, will not have any warning and will POST your form successfully.

You must check the values also in server-side.

EDIT:

Best way to go is always to do all the checks server-side, returning a page that explains the problem.

Then, use javascript to improve user experience, falling back to old method if it's disabled.

Comment: I guess knew that but hadn't really digested it. What is the generally accepted best way to do this? Should I put an error message in the page that it POSTs to?

Comment: Are there really that many people who disable js though? I guess that's what surprised me.

Comment: JS is considered a security problem in many environments, especially at work.

Comment: @pg. HTML5 has some features for FORM validation: http://www.the-art-of-web.com/html/html5-form-validation/

Comment: @A.Wolff but still, server side checks are ALWAYS necessary.